# Determine whether the graph below is isomorphic to Petersen graph.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, graph-isomorphism

At left is a graph, $G$, and at right is the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph).

[image][image]

I think they're isomorphic. I would like to know if I'm correct and how I can start a proof.

Answer (score 7):

They aren't isomorphic, because  the other graph has an obvious Hamiltonian cycle, but the Petersen graph is nonhamiltonian.

Answer (score 2):

No they are not isomorphic, since [G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0xkQ.png) has a loop with 4 vertices (C, J, G, D), and [the Petersen graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Ag3.png) has only loops of size 5. I drawed [G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0xkQ.png) in GeoGebra and moved the vertices around to get:

[image]